# Missing file in lib

Tags: javascript, typescript

I moved some files/folders around after in created a new project.  I am ready to deploy it so I did `gulp clean`.  I am now getting an error:

```
[16:35:29] Error - 'collectLocalizedResources' sub task errored after 3.53 ms
 Error for resource "HotDeliveryScheduleWebPartStrings": No localized files found under the root directory ("C:\...\dev\test04") matching pattern "lib/webparts/hotDeliverySchedule/loc/{locale}.js"
```

That file location:

[image]

Comment: The `en-us.js` locale is located in `lib/webparts/loc/en-us.js`, not in `lib/webparts/hotDeliverySchedule/loc/en-us.js`. Change your gulp script to reflect that.

Comment: It's looking for `webparts/hotDeliverySchedule/loc` but should be `webparts/loc`

Comment: Ugh, that was it! Thanks guys.  I had to do that for the manifest I thought I had looked at that.